# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: rProvider <- r <- notificationsBarDirective

Tags: angularjs, notifications

Tried to implement NotificationBar using this URL - [SampleURL](http://beletsky.net/ng-notifications-bar/)

JSCode - AngularJs 1.5

```
var app = angular.module('appVideo', ['ngSanitize', 'ngTouch', 'angucomplete-alt', 
'ngCookies', 'ngNotificationsBar']);

app.config(['notificationsConfigProvider', 
  function(notificationsConfigProvider) {
    notificationsConfigProvider.setHideDelay(5000);
    notificationsConfigProvider.setAutoHide(true);
    notificationsConfigProvider.setAcceptHTML(true);
  }
]);

app.$inject = ["$rootScope"];
app.$inject = ['notificationsConfigProvider'];

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$rootScope', '$cookies',
  '$location', 'notifications', 'storageService',
  function($scope, $http, $window, $rootScope, $cookies, 
    $location, notifications, storageService) {
    $scope.init = function() {
      notifications.showWarning('Alert Message');
    }
  }
]);
```

[image: Error Message Image]

Please suggest something.

Comment: Does this issue happen on stackblitz or you local?

Comment: @huanfeng - it's happening in production env. In local env, it works fine.

Comment: did you solve that?

Comment: @anatol - not yet, changed the notification system as of now.